# How to Make a Combo Box to Select Audio Input

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, microphone

I'm designing a voice recorder in WPF with C#, and I want the user to be able to choose what microphone (if there is more than one) they would like to use for input. I've seen several articles on this, but those are using 3rd-party API's (Like NAudio). I want to do this with no 3rd-party API's, and have it display in a combo box. Any ideas?

Comment: You'd need to provide something you tried. People won't just write the code for you.

Comment: @scharette That's the problem, I haven't tried anything because I've never seen this done before (e.g I don't have any idea how to). I'm not very advanced with C# yet, I started learning in March.

Comment: I understand, it happened a lot to me too when I started on Stack. I'm just trying to help you, because it is really unlikely that people will answer your question. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This project shows a selection of a combo box item whenever a user selects a different list view item:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWPFMasterDetailBinding-c78566ae

This works because both controls are bound to the SelectedCompressionLevel property in the OptionsViewModel:

```
SelectedValuePath="Key"
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCompressionLevel}"
```

The Key is necessary because this actually works with a dictionary from the CompressionLevels property.

You need to be more specific and post your own code if this answer is not helpful otherwise its impossible (for me) to read your mind and understand your problem :-(